# DirectX10 Only one rendertarget is drawn to

Tags: c++, c, directx, shader, hlsl

So I have added MRT to my program.

The Problem: My two textures (normalMap and positionMap) are empty (only filled with the clearcolor)..

I use them like this:

Inside of my header:

```
        ID3D10RenderTargetView** m_ppBuffer;
        ID3D10Texture** m_ppTextures;
        ID3D10ShaderResourceView** m_ppshaderView;
```

Each Frame:

```
this->m_pDevice->OMSetRenderTargets(this->m_TextureCount, this->m_ppBuffer, this->m_pDepthBuffer);
for (int32 i = 0; i < this->m_TextureCount; i++)
    this->m_pDevice->ClearRenderTargetView(this->m_pBuffer[i], a_Color.colors);
....
....
    this->m_pEffect->GetVariableByName("DiffuseMap")->AsShaderResource()->SetResource(m_ppshaderView[0]);
    this->m_pEffect->GetVariableByName("NormalMap")->AsShaderResource()->SetResource(m_ppshaderView[1]);
    this->m_pEffect->GetVariableByName("PositionMap")->AsShaderResource()->SetResource(m_ppshaderView[2]);
    this->m_pDevice->IASetInputLayout(this->m_pInputLayout);
    this->m_pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(0)->Apply(0);
    this->m_pDevice->IASetPrimitiveTopology(primitiveTopology);
    this->m_pDevice->Draw(a_Vertices, 0);
```

My Shader which I use to draw onto the rendertargets:

```
float4x4 Scale;
float4x4 Rotation;
float4x4 Translation;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;

Texture2D Diffuse;

SamplerState TextureSampler
{
  Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_Linear;
  AddressU = WRAP;
  AddressV = WRAP;
};
struct VertexShaderInput
{
  float3 Position : POSITION0;
  float2 UV       : TEXCOORD0;
  float3 Color    : COLOR0;
  float3 Normal   : NORMAL0;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
  float4 PositionOut : SV_POSITION;
  float4 Position : POSITION0;
  float2 UV       : TEXCOORD0;
  float3 Color    : COLOR0;
  float3 Normal   : NORMAL0;
};

struct PixelShaderOutput
{
  float4 colorMap: SV_TARGET0;
  float4 normalMap: SV_TARGET1;
  float4 positionMap: SV_TARGET2;
};


VertexShaderOutput VS_MAIN(VertexShaderInput input)
{
  VertexShaderOutput Output = (VertexShaderOutput)0;

  float4 pos = float4(input.Position.xyz, 1);

  float4x4 Model = mul(mul(Scale,Rotation),Translation);
  float4x4 MVP = mul(mul(Model,View),Projection);

  Output.Position = mul(pos,MVP);
  Output.PositionOut = mul(pos,MVP);

  Output.UV = input.UV;

  Output.Color = input.Color;

  Output.Normal = input.Normal;

  return Output;
}

PixelShaderOutput PS_MAIN(VertexShaderOutput input)
{
  PixelShaderOutput output;

  float4 blend = Diffuse.Sample(TextureSampler, input.UV);
  output.colorMap = blend;
  output.normalMap = float4(input.Normal,1);
  output.positionMap = float4(input.Position.xyz,1);

  return output;
}

RasterizerState Culling
{
  CullMode = 1;
};

technique10 Main
{
  pass p0
  {
    SetRasterizerState(Culling);
    SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, VS_MAIN()));
    SetGeometryShader(NULL);
    SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, PS_MAIN()));
   }
};
```

After that, I render my Rendertargets using one Quad and this shader.
TextureID is a value I defined in code so I can switch between the rendertarget textures during runtime using my arrows.

```
float4x4 Scale;
float4x4 Rotation;
float4x4 Translation;
float4x4 View;
float4x4 Projection;
float textureID;

Texture2D DiffuseMap;
Texture2D NormalMap;
Texture2D PositionMap;

SamplerState TextureSampler
{
  Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_Linear;
  AddressU = WRAP;
  AddressV = WRAP;
};
struct VertexShaderInput
{
  float3 Position : POSITION0;
  float2 UV       : TEXCOORD0;
  float3 Color    : COLOR0;
  float3 Normal   : NORMAL;
};

struct VertexShaderOutput
{
  float4 Position : SV_POSITION;
  float2 UV       : TEXCOORD0;
  float3 Color    : COLOR0;
  float3 Normal   : NORMAL;
};

struct PixelShaderOutput
{
  float4 color: SV_TARGET0;
};


VertexShaderOutput VS_MAIN(VertexShaderInput input)
{
  VertexShaderOutput Output = (VertexShaderOutput)0;

  float4 pos = float4(input.Position.xyz, 1);

  float4x4 Model = mul(mul(Scale,Rotation),Translation);
  float4x4 MVP = mul(mul(Model,View),Projection);

  Output.Position = mul(pos,MVP);

  Output.UV = input.UV;

  Output.Color = input.Color;

  Output.Normal = input.Normal;

  return Output;
}

PixelShaderOutput PS_MAIN(VertexShaderOutput input)
{
  PixelShaderOutput output;

  float4 blend = DiffuseMap.Sample(TextureSampler, input.UV);
  float4 norm = NormalMap.Sample(TextureSampler, input.UV);
  float4 pos = PositionMap.Sample(TextureSampler, input.UV);
  blend.a = 1;
  if(textureID == 0.0)
    output.color = blend;
  else if(textureID == 1.0)
    output.color = norm;
  else
    output.color = pos;

  return output;
}

RasterizerState Culling
{
  CullMode = 1;
};

technique10 Main
{
  pass p0
  {
    SetRasterizerState(Culling);
    SetVertexShader(CompileShader(vs_4_0, VS_MAIN()));
    SetGeometryShader(NULL);
    SetPixelShader(CompileShader(ps_4_0, PS_MAIN()));
   }
};
```

Comment: Did using a single render target work? You haven't included the actual draw calls in the code snippet, which may be the issue. If you believe it is your shader changes, try using a GPU frame capture tool... eg. PIX / Windows Graphics Diagnostics / Nsight, etc. This way, you can inspect why exactly the pixels are not being written.

Comment: there is something drawn to the first rendertarget, but not to the second or third. If using a single one, there will be something drawn to it.
I added the draw call above.

I will test it using a frame capture tool.

Answer (score 0):

I used the graphic debugger and that gave me the reason why it did not work!

I forgot to set the BlendState for my other Rendertarget's. Setting BlendEnable to true fixed it finally.

Comment: Exactly why they invented the frame debuggers :).